# ¿Cómo se conjuga el verbo "instanciar"?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, conjugación, informática, indicativa

El verbo *instanciar* parece que es [una de las aberraciones del spanglish](http://aberracionesespanglish.blogspot.com.es/2012/02/instanciar.html). El artículo que enlazo explica que:

> Curiosamente, proviene del latín “instantia”, que no se desarrolló de la misma manera en castellano (“instancia”) que en inglés (“instance” /’ɪnstəns/: “ejemplo”, “caso”). De esta última raíz surgió más adelante el verbo “to instantiate” que, teniendo en cuenta su origen, no debería traducirse nunca por “instanciar”, sino como “ejemplificar” o “ilustrar”. Lo mismo sería aplicable a “instanciación” (“ejemplo”, “ejemplificación”, “ilustración”). Del mismo modo, en castellano el verbo correspondiente al sustantivo “instancia” sería “instar” (o su sinónimo “solicitar”), nunca “instanciar”.

Sin embargo, debemos asumir que en el mundo de la informática se usa de forma generalizada para designar la materialización de objetos definidos abstractamente: tenemos una clase general y cada una de sus materializaciones son una instancia.

Pero mi duda está en el uso del verbo *instanciar*. ¿Cómo debe conjugarse? ¿Cuál de estas dos conjugaciones es correcta de la primera persona del singular en el presente del indicativo?

- Yo **instancio**
- Yo **instancío**

Es decir, ¿debe usarse tilde como en otros verbos del tipo fiar, enviar (yo fío, yo envío) o del tipo anunciar, presenciar (yo anuncio, yo presencio)?

Comment: No veo razón para no tratarlo igual que agencia->agenciar->[agencio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=14iOv4I), sustancia->sustanciar->[sustancio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YpTWS0u). Aparte de que hay más proximidad etimológica, los sustantivos relacionados (anuncio, presencia) también se forman regularmente y con diptongo (lo que no pasa con fianza ni envío).

Comment: Nótese que la diferencia (etimológica) entre sustancia e instancia es sólo de un prefijo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es complicado dar una respuesta totalmente correcta sobre un término que, como comentas, es una aberración spanglish y por tanto no está regulado.
Personalmente trato de no conjugarlo y uso *"creo una instancia"*.

Dicho esto, he escuchado más "yo instancio" o "tú instancias" que "instancío" o "instancías", pero esto puede ser algo local (en mi caso Barcelona, España) y puede que en otras regiones o países hispanohablantes sea distinto.

Edito para añadir el aporte de @Rafael en los comentarios de la pregunta: la conjugación de sustanciar puede ser el mejor ejemplo a seguir

Comment: Curioso, yo soy más o menos de esta zona y oigo más la variante con tilde. Esto sea probablemente por el influjo del catalán, en el que todos los verbos terminados en `-iar` se conjugan de manera que la palabra sea aguda (_jo env**i**o_, _jo presenc**i**o_, siempre con la tónica en la _i_). Sea como fuere, gracias y bienvenido a [spanish.se], Pablo.

Answer (score 2):

### instancio

Eso sería la correcta conjugación.   Si pusieras un tilde en la `i`, no sonara como el infinitivo.  No sé como se llama esta regla, pero así es.  La conjugacion debe sonar similar a la raíz del verbo.

Instanciar lleve su éstres en la primera 'a', y por eso hay que tratar de conjugar el verbo con el mismo ritmo/sonido.

Por ejemplo, el verbo "desgraciar".  **No** se lo conjugaría así

> Desgrac**í**o

Ni siquiera el verbo "graciar".

> Grac**í**o

Si el verbo fuera "instancíar" lo conjugarías con el tilde para mantener ese concordancia de sonido.

Otro ejemplo: "guiar".

El hecho que el infinitivo no lleva tilda en la "i" significa que es "i tónica", y tambien ya es la sílaba penúltima.  La "a" y la "i" no combinan en diptongo porque el "r" necesita esa "a" para desarrollar la última sílaba.  Pero cuando lo conjugas, no más hay un "r", y tienes que prevenir la formación de diptongos con un tilde.

> - Gu**í**o
> - Gu**í**as
> - Gu**í**a
> - Gu**í**an
> - Gu**í**amos

Por la misma razón movimos el tilde cuándo hacemos un mandato con objecto indirecto.

> Cántamelo

Si no lo muevas, sonara así

> Cantámelo - *puse el tilde por énfasis.*

Espero que eso tenga sentido.  Español no es mi lengua nativa.