# ¿Por qué los verbos terminados en "-iar" se dividen en dos acentuaciones distintas en el singular del presente?

Tags: etimología, verbos, conjugación, acentuación

Preguntando por [¿Cómo se conjuga el verbo "instanciar"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19246/c%C3%B3mo-se-conjuga-el-verbo-instanciar) me di cuenta de que los verbos terminados en *-iar* están divididos en dos grupos según cómo conjugan el singular del presente.

Fijémonos en *enviar* y *anunciar*, los cuales parecen compartir la raíz latina *-iāre*:

> [**enviar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FsWKK9o): Del lat. tardío inviāre 'caminar', 'recorrer'.
>
> [**anunciar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=30C6Foc): Del lat. annuntiāre.

La conjugación del singular en el presente presenta un sonido tónico en distinto lugar:

| persona | enviar | anunciar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| yo | env`í`o | an`u`ncio |
| tú | env`í`as | an`u`ncias |
| él, ella | env`í`a | an`u`ncia |

Es decir, en *enviar* se opta por romper el diptongo y decir */en-**ví**-o/*, mientras que en *anunciar* se mantiene y, por contra, la tónica recae en la *u* anterior: */a-**nun**-cia/*.

En el bloque de enviar me encuentro también con:

> [**fiar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Hq8iPy4): Del lat. *fidāre*, por *fidĕre*.

y otros me irán apareciendo.

¿Qué origen tiene tal distinción en la pronunciación de los verbos? ¿Viene de su raíz latina o hay algún proceso fonológico posterior que lo explique? ¿Se pueden efectivamente separar en dos grandes bloques o hay alguna otra posibilidad?

Comment: estas preguntando sobre el uso del acento grave?

Comment: si no uses un acento la conjugacion no sonara correcto.  Tendra un diptongo, y hay que prevenir esto con el acento.

Comment: @dockeryZ no, mi pregunta es por qué unos verbos de etimología supuestamente parecida tienen fonología distinta. Pero disculpa, mi enunciado no fue demasiado acertado. Acabo de actualizar para intentar que mi cuestión sea más clara.

Comment: Bueno, creo que allí tenemos mucha de la información.  Con anunciar, la *i* y *a* siempre iban juntos, algo que favorece diptongo.  Pero en *fiar*, venía de *fi-dar(-e)*, y seguramente la *d* se mantuvo lo suficiente para establecer una pronunciación bisilábica que se mantiene (nota que confiar como infinitivo se pronuncia con tres sílabas normalmente, y confiaré en cuatro, aunque en una habla más relajada puede reducirse por procesos similares a los que reducen *toalla* a *tualla*). Hay cosas interesantes que ocurren con los verbos *-ear* que deben estar relacionadas.  Pero no puedo escribir…

Comment: una respuesta completa de momento.  Quizás luego esta semana si nadie escribe nada cuando me libre.

Comment: @guifa ojalá saques tiempo para ella :))

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar, especificar que la RAE reconoce dentro de la conjugación de verbos regulares "los modelos de conjugación para cada uno de los dos grupos en que se dividen, en cuanto al acento, los verbos terminados en -iar y en -uar" (http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal). Y para el primer caso, propone como modelos los dos mencionados en la pregunta: **enviar** y **anunciar**. Análogamente podríamos haber hecho la pregunta con los modelos para el segundo caso: **averiguar** y **actuar**.

Mi primera impresión ha sido encontrar que los verbos "cortos" acentúan la i de la terminación -iar, mientras que los verbos "largos" dejan el acento en la vocal anterior. Aunque esta conclusión no parece demasiado precisa.

Así que, curioseando un poco más, he llegado a otra hipótesis: partiendo de que fonológicamente en español tendemos a evitar que la primera vocal de la palabra sea la tónica (por eso la mayor parte de las palabras son llanas y agudas, y evitamos las esdrújulas), cuando conjugamos "empujamos" el acento a la derecha para evitar que esto ocurra en los verbos "cortos".

Si estoy en lo correcto, en estos casos la regla o tendencia natural sería conjugar como "anunciar"; excepto si esto produce que la primera vocal sea la tónica. En ese caso, desplazamos el acento a la i.

El caso de "piar" y "fiar" no tiene otra solución, ya que no existe vocal previa al grupo -iar. Cuando existe una sola vocal anterior (desviar, aliar, ampliar...), desplazamos a la i de -iar. En los demás casos (expoliar, conciliar, exiliar...) conjugaríamos "normalmente".

Como curiosidad, tenemos el verbo "paliar", que se puede conjugar de ambas formas.

Comment: Qué curioso el caso de _paliar_, yo siempre dije _palío_ pues _palio_ solamente lo relaciono con el Papa de Roma. Sea como fuere, gracias por la respuesta Dertalai.