# cAusa but veAmos (strong, weak vowels)

Tags: pronunciación, acentuación, vocales

Could you explain to me why the combinations of two vowels are stressed differently? Are both of these combinations diphthongs?

Thank you

Edit: I found the proper explanation here *http://www.learn-spanish-amigos.com/diphthongs-in-spanish.html*

But now I do not understand this part there:

> If the first of 2 weak vowels coming together is accented, two
>   syllables are formed:
>
> Fluido (Flu-i-do) (fluid)

Comment: Are there any examples that you can provide? If you elaborate your question a little bit more you’ll get better and more targeted answers. Visit [ask] or check other highly upvoted questions to see how to write better questions that will help people understand what you don’t understand so they can write better tailored answers. Thanks and welcome to the stack.

Comment: @walen yes, it seems like this part of the explanation contradicts to the previous one.

Comment: @walen the "I" is the second week vowel ? isn't the "I" the strong prosodic accented vowel ?
finishing with "o" and not having the "o" accented that makes it "grave" , isn't it ?

Comment: got it! thank you, every day you learn something new !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The webpage you consulted makes a dreadful mix of phonetics (how things are pronounced) and orthography (how things are written) and is also not really using proper terms. So let's begin by that.

- The so-called "strong vowels" are in fact the [open or low vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_vowel) /a/ and the [mid vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_vowel): /e/ and /o/. A "strong" vowel is always syllabic and can always receive stress.
- The so-called "weak vowels" are the [close or high vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_vowel): /i/ and /u/. The special thing about these high vowels is that they can become **non-syllabic**, i.e. semiconsonantic, pronounced [j] and [w] respectively (like the English glides written *y* and *w*). Non-syllabic vowels are by definition part of a diphthong.
- Two vowels next to each other in Spanish may or may not form a diphthong. If they don't, they are said to be in [hiatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_(linguistics)).
- Strong vowels next to each other are always in hiatus.¹
- A strong vowel next to a weak one (in either order) can form a diphthong or not. If they don't, then the weak vowel must be marked with an accent mark (*r**í-o*** "river", ***o-í***r "to hear"). A strong+weak vowel group in an unstressed syllable is always a diphthong.²

Now on to your question:

Two weak vowels next to each other are most often pronounced as a [rising diphthong](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rising-diphthong) (*ui* = [wi], as in English *we* or French *oui*; *iu* = [ju], as in English *you*). The exceptions are few: *fluido* is often pronounced as three syllables, with a hiatus between *u* and *i*, and *muy* has a [falling diphthong](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/falling-diphthong) ([muj]). You can also find a hiatus in the verb *huir* [u.ir] and its derivates (depending on who's speaking), though not in *fui* [fwi], etc.

The combination *iu* is also almost always a diphthong, as in *ciudad, viuda, diurno, oriundo*, but it can have a short hiatus in *triunfo*. This might have something to do with the fact that there's a glide *r* in the [syllable onset](https://glossary.sil.org/term/onset), in the same way that there's an *l* in *fluido*.

**Notes:**

¹ Strong vowels next to each other are always *formally* in hiatus, *but* that's not really the case in fast speech, where unstressed *e* and *o* often become higher (closer to *i* and *u*) and non-syllabic. This is common across word boundaries and recognized especially in poetry ([synalepha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synalepha)).

² A strong+weak vowel group in an unstressed syllable is *nearly* always a diphthong. As pointed out in this question about [verbs ending in *-iar* and *-uar*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19445/por-qu%C3%A9-los-verbos-terminados-en-iar-se-dividen-en-dos-acentuaciones-distint), there are instances of unstressed *ia, ie, ua, ue* in some conjugations where the vowels are pronounced in hiatus. These verbs include *fiar*, *enviar*, *adecuar* and *actuar*.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. As for this part,  - A strong+weak vowel group in an unstressed syllable is always a diphthong. - doesn't it make au in causa a diphthong since it is stressed?

Comment: Oh, I get it. You meant if there is a strong+weak group and the stress is on another syllable, this makes them a diphthong.

Comment: Yes. The only way for a strong+weak group NOT to form a diphthong is if the diphthong is broken by stress over the weak vowel.

Comment: @pablodf76 I wouldn't say the *only* way.  For example, *enviamos* will be pronounced by most as four syllables, but the stress is on the the strong vowel.  But those cases are, admittedly, not particularly important for a learner because the difference between /en.vi'a.mos/ and /en'vja.mos/ is pretty small.  It perhaps happens more often from prefixes ending with vowels and base words starting with vowels: there's virtually always an implied hiatus (*preinstalación*, *antiaéreo*)

Comment: @guifa Yes, you're right about that (there's a whole subclass of verbs with that pattern, which I believe we've mentioned somewhere in another question).

Comment: @guifa - Wait, what?  Can you share a link to a recording of *enviamos* the way you're saying is common, and another including that in a sentence?  I don't think I've ever heard this pronounced as four syllables.

Comment: @aparente001 aquí puedes escuchar el anuncio de una empresa colombiana llamada *Enviamos* en su publicidad: https://youtu.be/uEhu4ceRhwQ

Comment: @guifa - Gracias, pero no sé qué pasa, no oigo 4 sílabas.

Comment: Not a native speaker, but sure sounds like four syllables to me.

Comment: @pablodf76  I was about to post a question involving the pronunciation of [**_guitarra_**](https://easypronunciation.com/en/spanish/word/guitarra) /ɡiˈtara/ and [**_fluido_**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fluido#Pronunciation_2) /fluˈido/ (although I now see that Wiktionary provides two pronunciations for _fluido_.  (The link to _fluido_ in this comment is to the Wiktionary entry for it.).  Nevertheless. this is yet another impressive answer from you.  I am so glad you so regularly contribute to this forum.

Answer (score 4):

There is no rule on how to place stress in combinations of vowels. It is the other way around. Any two vowels can be stressed in any way and, depending on whether they are both in the same syllable, and whether they are strong or weak, they either form diphthongs or they don't.

In your examples the vowels are divided into syllables like this:
+ Causa = Cau-sa.
+ Veamos = Ve-a-mos

So in *causa* the two vowels are in the same syllable and in *veamos* they are in different ones.

The combination "au" is considered a diphthong, as you already found, and the combination "ae" is not, as they are both strong vowels.

As for the second question: As I said before, any vowel could be the stressed one, so the reference says that in case of two weak vowels together **if the stress is on the first one** then they are pronounced as two separated syllables. And if they are in separated syllables then there is no diphthong. Again my point is that it is not that the combination of syllables tells you how to pronounce the word, but the pronunciation tells you if it is *diptongo* o *hiato* or neither.

After trying to look for other examples I think the **fluido** example shows that perhaps the reference is wrong and it should say **second** instead of **first**.

The syllable split for *fluido* in the reference is fine but the stress is on the i  (flu-**I**-do) because if the stress were on the **u** then the word would be considered *esdrújula* for having the stress on the third syllable (counting backwards) and then it would be written flúido. The main thing is that the pronunciation would put the two vowels in different syllables so there would be no diphthong there.

An example of a diphthong with ui combination is *buitre* (bui-tre) where both vowels are pronounced as one syllable.

I think you got confused thinking that this is a rule on how to pronounce a combination of vowels but for me diphthongs are not ways to help you pronounce words. The way to know how to pronounce a word is a combination of knowing this plus watching if the word has a "acute accent" (*tilde* á é í ó ú) and knowing when these *tildes* are used.

Comment: I like your approach.  I did some copyediting to make the answer easier to read, but please roll it back if my edits aren't helpful.

Comment: @aparente001 edits are welcome and appreciated. Tks.

Comment: I see what you're saying (and agree), but just as a side note, for me, as a native English speaker, knowing the rules of stress don't just help me pronounce words; they help me know how to spell them, too.  For that matter, knowing rules of stress may help some native Spanish speakers as well.  I've met more than one native Spanish speaker who has told me they can speak the language but don't know how to write it (because, presumably, they grew up in a home where it was spoken but not formally taught).