# ¿Por qué al conjugar "adecuar" la tilde es optativa?

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación, conjugación, acentuación

Acabo de encontrarme lo siguiente en un artículo de prensa:

> [...] el sistema se **adecua** a la perfección a las necesidades de los niños e impide que se frustren al no ser capaces de llegar a un determinado nivel [...]

Y me he quedado muy sorprendida al ver la palabra *adecua* así escrita, sin tilde. Así que he ido a la RAE a ver qué opinaba, y me he encontrado ([RAE, verbo adecuar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0iArrmH), pinchar botón de "conjugar") con que se aceptan ambas formas, *adecua* y *adecúa*. Es más, no es el único caso, sino que para muchísimas de las formas de la primera, segunda o tercera personal del singular sucede lo  mismo.

Creo que mi duda puede deberse a dos factores: por un lado empiezo a dudar que la única pronunciación válida sea /a·de·'cu·a/, y por otro lado, la acentuación de diptongos e hiatos siempre me ha traído de cabeza...

Así que, finalmente, preguntas: ¿alguien podría indicarme por qué se aceptan ambas formas? ¿Acaso es válida la pronunciación /a·'de·kua/? ¿Cuáles son las normas ortográficas pertinentes?

Comment: Curioso, acabo de ver que con [licuar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NGkMg0h) también pasa

Comment: Y con "evacuar" y "oblicuar", pero no con "anticuar". Otra incógnita más, ¿a qué verbos acabados en "-cuar" aplica y a cuáles no? ¿Por qué?

Comment: Relacionado a este asunto: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19445/por-qu%C3%A9-los-verbos-terminados-en-iar-se-dividen-en-dos-acentuaciones-distint/19626#19626

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Básicamente, en todo el mundo hispanohablante, se han surgido dos pronunciaciones.  Con una, la palabra raíz se considera ser A-DE-CU-AR, y con la otra, la palabra raíz se considera A-DE-CUAR.

Entonces, al conjugar en el presente (y algunos imperativos), vamos a pensar primero en lo oral y después en la ortografía:

```
Modelo a-de-cu-ar               Modelo a-de-cuar
-----------------               -----------------
a-de-cu-o   a-de-cu-a-mos       a-de-cuo   a-de-cua-mos
a-de-cu-as  a-de-cu-ais         a-de-cuas  a-de-cuais
a-de-cu-a   a-de-cu-an          a-de-cua   a-de-cuan
```

Ahora bien, recuerda que la sílaba tónica en el presente recae sobre la penúltima sílaba en todas las formas excepto en el vosotros (y pues también el vos) donde por razones históricas se ha perdido una sílaba y recae sobre la que ahora es la última.

```
Modelo a-de-cu-ar        Modelo a-de-cuar
------------------       -----------------
adecúo   adecuámos       adécuo   adecuámos
adecúas  adecuáis        adécuas  adecuáis
adecúa   adecúan         adécua   adécuan
```

Ahora debemos ver si los tildes son prescindibles.  Como las formas de nosotros y vosotros coinciden, los trato primero.  En *adecuamos*, sea que lo pronunciemos en cuatro o cinco sílabas, tendrá siempre la *a* acentuada.  Como se ubica en la penúltima sílaba y la palabra termina en *s*, no escribimos tilde en ningún caso.

Con el vosotros, pronunciado en tres o cuatro sílabas, siempre acentuamos la *a* que forma diptongo (o triptongo) con la *i*.  Encontrándose en la última sílaba y terminándose la palabra en *s*, tildamos la *a* para ambas pronunciaciones.

Para las otras personas, en el modelo /a.de.ku'ar/, si los tildes los quitamos, se interpreta la *ua* como el diptongo /wa/ y no como dos sílabas con hiato /u.a/, y como consecuencia, la penúltima sílaba llega a ser la *e*.  Por esta razón, aquel tilde es necesario porque sin él, ya no marca la pronunciación deseada.

Pero en el otro modelo de /a.de'kwar/, como ya indicamos, si quitamos los tildes sobre *adecuo*, etc, por formar diptongo la *u* con la *a* u *o*, la acentuación ya recae sobre la *e* que es precisamente donde la queremos.  Así que en este modelo, no hay tildes.

Para los hablantes, decidir si deben escribir *adecúa* o *adecua* depende por completo de lo que dicen en lo oral.  Si dicen /a.de'ku.a/ escriben pues *adecúa*, pero si dicen /a'de.kwa/, deben escribir *adecua*.

¿Por qué existen dos formas?  Buena pregunta.  Pero podemos ver poco a poco la entrada de una vacilación parecida con los verbos terminados en *-ear* y quizás los de *-uar* tuvieron un proceso parecido.    En algunas zonas, aquella terminación se ha convertido en *iar*, lo cual también ha implicado una modificación en cuál es la sílaba tónica.  Así es posible escuchar *yo pasio* /'pa.sjo/ en vez de *yo paseo* /pa'se.o/.  De momento, mientras la ASALE reconoce la existencia del cambio, no recomienda ninguna modificación en lo escrito (que no obligaría ningún tilde, ya que la *e*, siendo vocal fuerte, toma el lugar de una hipotética *í*).  Pero podemos imaginar un futuro en el cual se aceptan las dos formas e igual es posible que algunas palabras, por una razón u otra, no adopten el cambio, dejándonos con una situación parecida a los verbos en *-uar*.

Fuente: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=adecuar

Comment: me parece una respuesta magnífica y confirma lo que sospechaba: que hay dos variantes de pronunciación que dan lugar a dos variantes ortográficas. Sin embargo, ¿cómo lo has confirmado? ¿Por tu propia experiencia o por alguna fuente en particular?

Comment: @Alicia yo he escuchado y ambas formas, pero el DPD también explica tanto para adecuar como para otras palabras como licuar, etc, que ambas formas son frecuentes y válidas, pero que en el lenguaje culto se da preferencia por las formas diptongadas.  Yo personalmente tengo hiato en *adecuar* y *evacuar*, pero diptongo en *licuar* y *oblicuar*, aunque no tengo ni por qué

Comment: La referencia para quien le interese --> http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=adecuar