# Are both usages of *surgir* correct?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbo-pronominal

I learned to use *surgir* like this:

> Han surgido dos pronunciaciones.

But here at Spanish Language SE I've seen this:

> Se han surgido dos pronunciaciones.

Are both usages correct everywhere?  Is this a regionalism?

Comment: I have never seen "surgirse". Be aware nonetheless that @guifa writes in a very peculiar way that amuses even us native speakers. Maybe you should ask him why he wrote that [in this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25952/12637).

Comment: @Charlie interestingly, when I saw this question, the first thing I did was google "se han surgido" and sure enough most of the results are from Spain :P  But more interestingly is that in Argentina, there seems to be a trend to use it in the passive (fueron surgidos).  But although perhaps i picked it up from somewhere,  it may just be overzealous *se* usage in my Castilian (Portuguese and Asturian use it much less, so sometimes I think I compensate by overusing it in Castilian).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Charlie, the second is not common in Spain. It sounds wrong but I can not assure 100% that is grammatically wrong.

But let's take a look to the RAE's dictionary

**surgir** 
Del lat. surgĕre.

> 1. intr. Dicho del agua: Surtir, brotar hacia arriba.
> 2. intr. Aparecer o **manifestarse**, brotar.

**manifestar**

> 1. tr. Declarar, dar a conocer. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. Descubrir, poner a la vista. U. t. c. prnl.
> 3. tr. Exponer públicamente el Santísimo Sacramento a la adoración de los fieles.
> 4. tr. Poner en libertad y de manifiesto, en virtud del despacho del justicia mayor de Aragón, a quienes imploraban este auxilio para ser
>      juzgados.
> 5. **prnl**. Tomar parte en una manifestación pública.

**prnl** denotes that this verb is **pronominal**

**verbo pronominal**

> 1. m. Gram. verbo que se construye en todas sus formas con pronombres reflexivos átonos que no desempeñan ninguna función sintáctica y que
>      concuerdan con el sujeto; p. ej., me arrepentí, se levantó.

Notice that **surgir** is **not** labeled as **pronominal**.

Somehow "se han surgido" sounds redundant to a person from Spain, like "se se han manifestado". *surgir* alone is equivalent to *manifestarse*

Comment: Where the verbs *manifestar* and *aparecer* have semantic overlap with *surgir*, they can both be used as intransitives or pronominatives.  I don't think comparing *surgir* to them, consequently, says much: "Algo manifestó en X* y "algo se manifestó en X" are synonymous, just as is "algo apareció" and "algo se apareció".

Comment: No, "manifestar" is pronominal in 1. 2. and 5. You do not say "El fantasma manifestó en la habitación" if you mean that the phantom appears, you say "El fantasma se manifestó". Surgir is not pronominal, at least that is what the Academy established.

Comment: @guifa "se surgió" may be common in other zones of Spain (I'm from Andalucia) or other countries but is not correct. Note: Forgot to mention you in the above comment.