# ¿Qué término o palabra en español usar para evitar el spanglish "instanciación"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática, inglés

En la Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO) es muy frecuente que al crear objetos usemos estructuras informáticas que denominamos [instancias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instancia_(inform%C3%A1tica)). En algunas páginas de informática, he visto que utilizan el spanglish [*instanciación*](https://medium.com/nowports-tech/oop-instanciaci%C3%B3n-funcional-e-instanciaci%C3%B3n-de-clase-pseudocl%C3%A1sica-883b1008731a), lo cual me crea dudas acerca del uso de correcto de tal palabra, debido a que dicha palabra no se encuentra en el [Diccionario de la RAE](https://dle.rae.es/). Consultando este foro, he encontrado que la traducción de las palabras derivadas de "instancia" usada en la POO (por ejemplo, [¿Cómo se conjuga el verbo "instanciar"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19246/c%C3%B3mo-se-conjuga-el-verbo-instanciar)) generan dudas acerca de su uso correcto; ¿existe alguna palabra, oración u término que sea correcto para describir la acción de usar instancias, para evitar el uso de "instanciación"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que la acepción de "**instancia**", como componente informático, no está recogida por la RAE, tampoco lo está la de un verbo como "**instanciar**" que hace referencia a la creación de objetos de una clase en informática.

Si no esta seguro de que palabra usar o ¿por qué?, lo mejor es que utilice otro tipo de expresión o término que describa esa acción de crear instancias u objetos de una clase como representación concreta y especifica,  de esta manera podrá evitar la locución "**instancia**" o "**instanciación**".

La **instancia** u **objeto** de una clase, es una representación concreta y específica de la clase y esta reside normalmente en la memoria del ordenador. Así pues un sinónimo de "**instancia**" es "**objeto**", pues la instancia es un objeto creado y la "**creación de objetos**" sería la forma de decir "**instanciación**".

De esta manera, un "objeto" es una instancia de una clase y la "**creación de objetos**" materializan la clase, pues son objetos concretos que poseen su propio comportamiento (métodos que pueden ejecutar) y sus propias cualidades (atributos).

**Un poco de historia "Etimológica"**.

La palabra "**instantia**" procede del latín, sin embargo el término que utilizamos como acepción de "**creación de objetos**" (instancia) en informática y que la RAE no recoge, procede del inglés "**instance**". La antigua voz latina "**instantia**" tenía como significado el "**cumplimiento**" de algo y el de "**presencia**", normalmente de un hecho. Esta acepción de "**presencia**" de algo, es la que paso al inglés y en español, fue interpretada de manera distinta. De hecho las "instancias" son "**presencias**" que intentan asemejarse a algo, de ahí que "instance" se traduzca como "**ejemplo o caso**" "*for instance*" (por ejemplo) o "*in many instances*" (en muchos casos), ya que el concepto de la voz "*ejemplo*", conlleva la "*presencia*" de un caso o un hecho, que aunque no igual, se parece a otra cosa. Siendo entonces las "**instancias**", "*ejemplos*", "*presencias*" u "*objetos*" de la clase.

Por tanto, mi consejo si lo tiene a bien, es que utilice la fórmula "**creación de un objeto**" en lugar de "instancia" o "**creación de objetos**" en lugar de "instanciación".

**P.D.** Como curiosidad banal y simplemente de forma anecdótica sin valoración y de manera forzada, también se podría hablar de "instaurar" como sinónimo de "crear", ya que en una de sus acepciones en el latín clásico "instauro" (**insta**urāre), poseía el significado de "repetir", así que "instaurar objetos" sería algo como "repetir objetos".

Answer (score 1):

La mayoría de las veces, *instantiate* es una forma rebuscada de referirse a la construcción de un objeto de una clase. Así que se pueden usar las palabras *construir* o *crear*:

- We now instantiate an (object of the class) ExternalEmployee
- Ahora construimos/creamos un (objeto de la clase) ExternalEmployee

De hecho, la mayoría de los títulos de los apartados del [artículo enlazado en la pregunta](https://medium.com/nowports-tech/oop-instanciaci%C3%B3n-funcional-e-instanciaci%C3%B3n-de-clase-pseudocl%C3%A1sica-883b1008731a) contienen las palabras *crear* o *construir*.

Comment: Sería correcto también poder usar la palabra "generar" como otra opción de instantiate? Usando el ejemplo mencionado: Ahora generamos un (objeto de la clase) ExternalEmployee.

Comment: @LukeSolo sí, "generar" también suena bien.

Answer (score 1):

Muy bien. Acá hay tres cosas a tener en cuenta sobre la palabra **instanciación**:

En primer lugar, dicha palabra NO es un verbo. La **nominalización** es una regla de formación de palabras, que consiste en la creación de sustantivos a partir de verbos o a partir de adjetivos, mediante sufijos característicos (-ción, -miento-, -ada, -dad, -ncia, etc.).

> Instanciar --> Instancia**ción**

Es una técnica muy usada en el discurso científico o técnico ya que permite mejorar la precisión en el lenguaje. La palabra en cuestión es un ejemplo de la puesta en práctica de dicho concepto, y se pueden encontrar otros diccionarios que [sí la recogen](https://deleahora.com/diccionario/instanciaci%C3%B3n). Por lo tanto no es subestándar ni parte del *spanglish*; ni tampoco aplica el concepto de conjugación de verbos.

Segundo, no necesariamente porque una palabra no aparezca en el diccionario significa que sea incorrecto su uso. Además, el diccionario de la RAE es superficial al momento en el cual uno pretende usarlo para buscar términos regionales, especializados o neologismos. Que no te parezca raro si no aparecen palabras como esas.

Por último, dudo mucho que existan términos más técnicos y formales que puedan expresar el mismo significado y con las mismas connotaciones. A diferencia de las demás respuestas, no considero apropiado *creación*, o por lo menos no es algo tan formal ya que suele tener connotaciones de espontaneidad o misticismo — la Tierra es una creación de Dios, una determinada obra es la creación de un cierto artista, etc. Pero en la ciencia nada es *creado* con este sentido así que no te recomiendo esta opción. Si aún no estás convencido de que es correcto el uso de la palabra que trajiste, te ofrezco dos opciones similares:

- **Declaración** del objeto: si se prototipó sin haber reservado memoria para que efectivamente exista.
- **Inicialización** del objeto: si se reservó la memoria para el objeto y la información del mismo fue escrita con valores iniciales predefinidos.

Ah, y por cierto, ¡qué pena que ninguna de las dos entradas aparezca tampoco en el diccionario de la RAE! Parece que vamos a tener que hacerles una lista con términos y acepciones nuevas.

PD: Sí, obviamente esto no es una invitación ni estoy sugiriendo el uso de palabras anticuadas, de 'calcos' del inglés cuando hay equivalentes perfectos en nuestro idioma. Pero este no es el caso, así que no debe haber vergüenza en el uso de la misma.

Answer (score 1):

Nunca se me ha ocurrido traducir "*instantiate*" como "*instanciar*", ni "*instance*" como "*instancia*". Me parecen unos peligrosos falsos amigos.

De acuerdo con @wimi, cuando tenemos una clase como, por ejemplo, `Session`, lo más habitual es "*crear/construir un objeto de la clase Session*" o más simplemente "*crear/construir una Session*".

Por añadir algo más respecto a "*instance*", algo que he usado frecuentemente en mis aburridos informes y documentación es es "*ejemplar*". Por ejemplo, "*un ejemplar de [la clase] Session)"*.

Pero eso es en el lenguaje formal de un informe. Lo normal en el lenguaje hablado es decir "*una Session*" y nadie confunde el objeto con la clase.

Comment: Me parece que la palabra ejemplar captura todo el significado de instancia y además tiene la ventaja de ser conocida y de mayor uso.